# java sockets SocketException socket closed

Tags: java, sockets

I extended the Socket class and run into some errors that I do not understand, so i seek your help.  Below is a short snippet - nothing much. If I inserted the wrong host address, the first time it gives an error as `operation time out`. However the subsequent times when i try to use a valid address, the error says `socket closed`. I did not explicitly close the socket and the println says `socket closed is false`. Any idea why did the socket closes?

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at edu.astar.i2r.ppdf.exchange.p2p.PeerClient.connect(PeerClient.java:251)
    at edu.astar.i2r.ppdf.exchange.p2p.PeerClient.connectToServer(PeerClient.java:89)
    at edu.astar.i2r.ppdf.demo.ui.client.peertopeer.P2PParamsPage$1.actionPerformed(P2PParamsPage.java:87)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)



@Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress endPoint) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("socket closed is " + this.isClosed());
        super.connect(endPoint);
        logger.info("Connected to server...");

        this.ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.getOutputStream());
        this.istream = new ObjectInputStream(this.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that your application has already closed the socket and is now attempting to keep using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that somewhere in the entire program, you have called close() to the socket itself or either of ObjectOutputStream or ObjectInputStream or any other reader/writer used in the program.
Try commenting out all the .close() statements in the entire program and run the program again. Don't forget to have them in uncommented as soon as you found out the problem.